# Calculate the amount of milliseconds from current time to a certain time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, timer

So I have a string `currentTask.time` which stores a value that looks like this '13:00'.

Is there a way to calculate based on the current system time, the number of milliseconds until it will be that time again?

So basically, let's say the time is 12:59, if I should call this function passing '13:00' it should return 60000...

Not really sure the best way to approach this...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `var result = (Time1 - Time2).TotalMilliseconds;` in your case `var result = (DateTime.Now - DateTime.ParseExact(currentTask.time, "H:m", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).TotalMilliseconds;`

Answer (score 2):

This code assumes you're working with UTC datetimes.

If you're working with local times then you'll quite likely run in to problems such as the switch to and from daylight savings time.

```
// The time of day in hh:mm
var rawTime = "13:00";

// Parse the time
var time = TimeSpan.Parse(rawTime);

// Todays date, with the parsed time
var then = DateTime.UtcNow.Date + time;

// Todays date with the current time
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

// If the parsed time has already passed then move forward a day
if(then < now)
    then = then + TimeSpan.FromDays(1);

// How long until the parsed time
var duration = then - now;          
var durationInMilliseconds = duration.TotalMilliseconds;

Console.WriteLine(duration); // 22:35:41.4646691
Console.WriteLine(durationInMilliseconds + "ms"); // 81341464.6691ms
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/sre6V5

Answer (score 1):

First, convert it to a date time:

```
//note: you can also use ParseExact if you need a specific format.
var dt = DateTime.Parse(currentTask.time);
```

Then, subtract it from the current time, the result is a [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
//note, normal time difference is the other way roud: DateTime.Now - dt
var ts = dt - DateTime.Now;
```

Your result is in the `TotalMilliseconds` property. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds?view=netframework-4.7.2

Note that this has an incurrency of about 3-6 ms. If you need more precission, use a [StopWatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.7.2)

---

#### update

In your specific scenario, there is no date. In that case you can create 2 `TimeSpans`:

```
var yourTotalMilliSeconds = 
                   (new DateTime(hours, minutes, seconds)TimeOfDay - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay)
        .TotalMillisenconds;
```